# Proving if $E_1$ is compact, then ${\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty E_n}\ne\emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I was wondering if my proof/solution for i & ii was fine. Any feedback is greatly appreciated, please. Thank you.
$\def\R{{\mathbb R}}                            % real numbers
\def\N{{\mathbb N}}$

Let $E_1\supseteq E_2\supseteq \,\cdots\,\supseteq E_k\supseteq \,\cdots$ be a decreasing sequence of nonempty, closed subsets of $\R^n$.

(i) Prove if $E_1$ is compact, then $\displaystyle{\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n}\ne\emptyset$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Assume $E_1$ is compact. Since each $E_n$ is non-empty, choose a point $x_n \in E_n$ for all $n\in\N$. Then $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $\R^n$. Now, each $E_n\subseteq E_n$ for all $n\ge 2$. So, $x_n \in E_1$ for all $n\in \N$.

Now, $E_1$ is compact. So $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence. Let $\{x_{n_k}\}$ be the subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ which converges to $x\in \R^n$.

Our claim is that $\displaystyle{x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n}$. As $x_{n_k} \to x$, so every neighbourhood of $x$ contains all, but excepting finitely many possibly.

Now, for all $n\in \N, x_m\in E_n$ for all $m\ge n$ as $x_m \in E_m \subseteq E_n$ for all $m\ge n$ implies $x_{n_k} \in E_n$ for all $m\ge n$. Therefore, as $n_m \ge m$ implies each neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $E_n$ and implies $x\in \overline{E_n} = E_n$, $E_n$ is closed, for all $n\in \N$. So, $\displaystyle{x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n}$.

(ii) Provide an example of a sequence as above with the property $\displaystyle{\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n}=\emptyset$.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ Take $E_k = \N \setminus \{1,2,3,\dots , k\}$ for all $k\in \N$. Then each $E_k$ is a closed subset of $\R$. Also, $E_1\supseteq E_2\supseteq \dots$ . Now, $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n = \N\setminus \{1,2,3, \dots\} = \emptyset.$$ Thus, $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence of closed nonempty subsets of $\R$ with $\displaystyle{\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n = \emptyset}.$

Comment: I think it's easier to note that all $E_i$ are compact since closed subsets of compact sets are compact, and it's quite well known that a decreasing series of compact sets has non-empty intersection.

Comment: Your proof is correct. If your only available definition of compactness is that every sequence has a convergent subsequence, it’s a perfectly reasonable choice. Note, though, that that is actually the definition of a different property, sequential compactness, that is not equivalent to the general topological notion of compactness, though the two notions are equivalent in $\Bbb R^n$. There is a much easier argument using the usual general definition of compactness (every open cover of the space has a finite subcover).

Comment: A simple example: $E_k=[k+\infty)$ with $k\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: If the main point of your post is to get feedback on your proof, you can use the ([tag:solution-verification]) tag to indicate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, if your definition of *compact* is sequential compactness (i.e., in terms of sequences).

What you have proved here is known as [Cantor's intersection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem), you can compare your proof with that on Wikipedia which is basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing $ x_{n}\in E_{n},\ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right)\cdot $ And $ \left(x_{\varphi\left(n\right)}\right) $ the subsequence of $ \left(x_{n}\right) $ that converges to $ x\in E_{1} \cdot $

If $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, then since $ \left(\forall p\geq n\right),\ E_{p}\subset E_{n} $, we have that $ \left(x_{p}\right)_{p\geq n} $ is a sequence of points of $ E_{n} \cdot $ And since it does converge to $ x $ and $ E_{n} $ is closed, then $ x\in E_{n} \cdot $

Since $ n $ is arbitrary in $ \mathbb{N} $, then $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ x\in E_{n} $, thus $ x\in\bigcap\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{E_{n}} $, meaninig $$ \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{E_{n}}\neq\emptyset $$

Answer (score 0):

This works in every Hausdorff space, where compact implies closed.

It is not restrictive to assume that the whole space is $E_1$. Define $A_i=E_1\setminus E_i$, so $A_i$ is open. If
$$
\bigcap_{i\ge1}E_i=\emptyset
$$
then also
$$
\bigcup_{i\ge1}A_i=E_1
$$
Since $A_i$ is open in $E_i$ which is compact, there is a finite subcover. As the sequence $A_i$ is increasing, this implies that $A_k=E_1$ for some $k$, hence $E_k=\emptyset$.

---

You can simplify your proof by observing that, once you have chosen the subsequence $x_{n_k}\to x$, you have
$$
\bigcap_{k}E_{n_k}=\bigcap_{n}E_n
$$
Hence it is not restrictive to assume that $x_n\to x$ to begin with.

If $x\notin E_n$, for some $n$, then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $E_n\cap U=\emptyset$. But then $x_m\notin U$, for every $m>n$, contradicting convergence.