# if $\{S_m\}_{m=1}^\infty $ is infinite sequence of nonempty compact sets and $S_1 \supset S_2 \supset... $, then their intersection $\not= \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis

Question from a Real Analysis textbook:

Use the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorum to show that if $S_1, S_2, ... , S_m$ is an infinite sequence of nonempty compact sets and $S_1 \supset S_2 \supset... \supset S_m \supset ...$, then $\cap_{m = 1}^\infty S_m$ is nonempty. Show that the conclusion does not follow if the sets are assumed to be closed rather than compact.

I can see how the first part is true intuitively, as they are all contained in eachother and nonempty and therefore their intersection should not be empty, but I am not sure how to prove this. Also, I am not understanding how this is not true if the sets are just closed rather than compact.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3609567/proving-if-e-1-is-compact-then-displaystyle-bigcap-n-1-infty-e-n-ne-em).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are all non-empty, for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$ you might choose an element $x_m\in S_m$. All the elements from the sequence $(x_m)$ belong to the compact set $S_1$ and hence this is a bounded sequence, and by Bolzano-Weierstrass it has a convergent subsequence $x_{m_k}\to x$. Now we can show that $x$ belongs to the intersection. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and we'll show that $x\in S_n$. There exists some $k_0$ such that $m_{k}>n$ for all $k\geq k_0$. By definition for all $k\geq k_0$ we have $x_{m_k}\in S_{m_k}\subseteq S_n$. This shows that $(x_{m_k})_{k=k_0}^\infty$ is a convergent sequence of elements in $S_n$. Since $S_n$ is closed it follows that the limit of this sequence (which is $x$) must also belong to $S_n$.

This is not true if the sets are only closed, and not compact. For example let $S_n=[n, \infty)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then the intersection is empty. The difference is that Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem is about bounded sequences, so you will not be able to apply it here.